# I am getting a TypeError saying that a variable is nil, but I am not sure why

Tags: ruby

Ok so I am trying to write a simple binary search on an array of primes. But it seems that for some reason an assigned variable is nil. But when I check in irb the variable max and min both have a value.

here is the command line error: 
    Binarysearch.rb:15:in `[]': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
     from Binarysearch.rb:15:in`search'
     from Binarysearch.rb:33:in `'

This is the code:

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
target = 43

def search(primes, target)
 range = (primes.size) - 1
 min = (range - range).to_i
 max = range.to_i
 operations = 0 

if primes[min] == target || primes[max] == target
    puts "#{target}"
else
   while primes[max] >= primes[min] 
       b = (min + max)/2
       check = primes[b]
   if check == target
       puts "index #{primes[check]}"
       puts "this took #{operations}"
       break
   end
      if check < target
        min = primes[check + 1]
      elsif check > target
        max = primes[check - 1]
      end
     operations += 1
     end
   end
end

search(primes)
```

Comment: your method requires 2 arguments but you are only passing 1?

Comment: yeah, I have noticed that, but i don't understand why primes the array i defined is not passing into the method parameter primes

Comment: Often `min = (range - range).to_i`  will be zero.

Comment: oh yeah i know, I originally assigned min = 0 but it was saying that min and max were nil, so I changed it. But it is just a starting value. But the issue seems to be for some reason primes the array does not seem to be passing into the parameter primes in my method and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `check` equal to one of your primes.

```
check = primes[b]
```

Imagine (for example) that check contains 53.

Now, in *this* code, you're setting min or max to a value equal to Prime array element 54 or 52...

```
  if check < target
    min = primes[check + 1]
  elsif check > target
    max = primes[check - 1]
  end
```

However, you don't have than many primes elements, so min (or max) is set to `nil`

(When you reference an array element outside the range of the array, you always get nil)

```
array = [2,4]
p array[6]
#-> nil
```

Comment: thank you,  i changed it so that min and max are assigned b plus or minus so that when B gets recalculated it will narrow the search range.